# Invalid characters in label_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb

I'm constructing a simple form in ERB but the HTML produced by the text_field tag makes the *for* attribute in the label tag invalid.

```
<div>
  <p><%= label_tag "email[name]", "Name" %></p>
  <%= text_field :email, :name, :class => "text_field" %>
</div>
```

Produces the HTML

```
<div>
  <p><label for="email[name]">Name</label></p>
  <input class="text_field" id="email_name" name="email[name]" size="30" type="text" />
</div>
```

Which results in the error

> character "[" is not allowed in the
>   value of attribute "for".

How do I generate the text with without the nested parameter name email[name] to change the label tag *for* attribute? Is there an alternative approach that produces valid HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The for attribute is supposed to reference the ID attribute of the element for which it is  the label, not its name.

Therefore, don't you need:

```
<div>
  <p><%= label_tag "email_name", "Name" %></p>
  <%= text_field :email, :name, :class => "text_field" %>
</div>
```

...?

Answer (score 0):

Take it out of the quotes, or generate the div content as a string and add it to the div.innerHTML